# Add more Polyurethane to recently refinished hardwood flooring?

Tags: wood, hardwood-floor, hardwood-refinishing

Back in February 2016 I refinished my own hardwood floors.  I had a couple guys come in at the end and do the staining and polyurethane because I was spent...

We have a few areas of high traffic in the house that I think need some more polyurethane to protect the floors.  They also seem to scratch rather easily.

What is the best approach to only adding poly?  Keep in mind that I have 1200 sqft of hardwood and there is no way I can do all of it at this time so it will just the kitchen and main corridor maybe 500 sqft.

My plan is just to hit the floor with a fine grit screening pad on a flooring buffer.  Then sweep, lightly mop and apply the same poly used previously.  I think it will blend nicely since it is low sheen satin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone reading this I did as I said and it came out really well.  Process was to get a 220 grit screening pad and hand sand all the edges.  Then I cut a piece to go on my finish sander and hit the whole kitchen lightly.  Then I swept and mopped.

Painted on semi-satin polyuruthane with a brush.  I used Semi, because I was informed than for a satin finish you only want to do a satin base coat or else it will come out milky.

The kitchen looks much better now and I will repeat the process on the rest of the house when I have time.